# Why don't Stack<T> and Queue<T> have Capacity property while List<T> does?

Tags: c#, list, stack, queue, capacity

Is Capacity property more useful in a List than in the other collections such as Stack and Queue? Or is there another way to get the capacity of a Stack or a Queue?

Comment: The Queue<T> and Stack<T> both have Count properties which are similar to the capacity, no idea why they haven't included the capacity property though. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy0wwyz4.aspx

Comment: @JamieHennerley: Count and Capacity is *not* the same. `Count` is the amount of items you stored in the structure. `Capacity` is the amount of items the internal array can store. `Capacity` is never smaller than `Count`. Normally, it is bigger than `Count`. If it equals `Count` and you want to add another item, the internal array gets copied into a new array with a bigger capacity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the reason that `List` has a `Capacity` property and `Stack` and `Queue` do not is that the normal usage of those types is different.

For a `List` it is fairly common to populate it with a large set of values, even some time after it has been created. Providing the `Capacity` property (and constructor argument) helps to mitigate the number of reallocations that would be done when adding a large number of items to the list.

`Stack` and `Queue` on the other hand do not tend to have large numbers of items added to them at once *after* they've been created.

Presumably Microsoft decided that it wasn't worth adding the `Capacity` property because it wouldn't be used very much.

However, do note that [Queue does have a constructor that allows you to specify an initial capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35bz1ab7.aspx), and [so does Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahc986x9.aspx).

Also note that both classes also have a [`TrimExcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132388.aspx) method, as mentioned by @drch below.

So Microsoft thought it would be useful at construction time, but not useful later on - so they only added the capacity functionality to the constructors.

(Incidentally I've just had a quick check through our code base, and it seems that the only time we use a capacity for `List` is in fact at construction time. So maybe if Microsoft were designing List now, they might also omit the `Capacity` property for List...)

Comment: There's also TrimExcess() which sets the capacity to the current count if the internal array is not at least 90% full.

Answer (score 3):

`Stack` and `Queue` are LIFO and FIFO structures respectively.

In both cases, you (as a consumer of the API) generally only need to know how to put data into the structure, and how to get data out again.  You aren't concerned with the length of the data structure, only with `push` and `pop`.

If you need to get the capacity for any reason (a bounded stack/queue perhaps?) then it'd probably be better to hide that detail from the end user and implement your own stack/queue structure.

Comment: But Stack and Queue both have `Count` properties... The `Capacity` property exists only for optimization purposes (which would presumably also apply to Stack and Queue as well as List).

Comment: That's a weird one.  Both stacks and queues are commonly implemented using linked lists (where a capacity wouldn't help), but that's an example of an implementation detail leaking out.  Perhaps that's the point, if `Capacity` was defined that would give a big clue on the underlying implementation.

Comment: Well, you *can* set the initial capacity of List and Queue by using the right constructor. The parameter name is even `capacity`...

Comment: `List` is a concrete type that hints at the underlying implementation ("Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index") so that seems fine to have a capacity.  `LinkedList` on the other hand, doesn't provide such a constructor.

Comment: Indeed, but the point is that `Stack` and `Queue` *do* allow you to specify a capacity.

Answer (score 2):

This information is not exposed by `Stack<T>` or `Queue<T>`. This information isn't even stored explicitly in those classes, only implicitly in form of the length of the internal array.

Your only option to get that would be to use reflection to access the array and get it's length.